# Code with minimum time complexity to find occurrence of max and min Character in a String

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have to find the best possible solution to find occurrence of min and max character in given string.

Code i am using is as below

```
 String prefix="aaaaabbbbddddfeeeee"
 HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabetCountMapInit = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();         

 //Time Complexity : O(n)
 for (char c : prefix.toCharArray()) {
            alphabetCountMapInit.put(c, alphabetCountMapInit.get(c) == null ? 1 : alphabetCountMapInit.get(c) + 1);
          }   

  //Time Complexity :  O(n)
  int minOccurence = Collections.min(alphabetCountMapInit.values());
  System.out.println(maxOccurance);

  //Time Complexity :  O(n)
  int maxOccurence = Collections.max(alphabetCountMapInit.values());  
  System.out.println(minOccurance);
```

`

Can anyone suggest me a solution more optimized in terms of time complexity, as I need to iterate for around 90^90 number of string records.?

Comment: Maybe keep track of the min and max values inside the `for`. Set max to -1 and min to +1 before the for loop. Then after 1 to the count `if(alphabetCountMapInit.get(c) > max){ max = ..}` and vice versa for the min

Comment: Collections.min and Collections.max are O(n)

Comment: @EricG This too is `O(n)`

Comment: 90^90 is a huge number. I don't think you'll be finishing that task in your lifetime. Come to think of it, that might take longer than the expected life of the universe.

Comment: @JimMischel I think it might be a 90*90 array of Strings.

Comment: By 90^90 I mean  - 90 power 90 array of string.  Example - aaa,aaaa........, 90^90

Comment: Sieiman , you r right updated Time complexity

Comment: @Sieiman , you r right updated Time complexity in my question

Comment: (Your attempts to alert [Sleiman Jneidi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/822588/sleiman-jneidi) seem to have gone astray - don't you get suggestions pausing to type after `@Slei`?) Like @JimMischel I hesitate to expect my interpretation of `90^90` (~7,6×10^175 - too big for Java arrays) to be what you are confronted with, and I don't get the `aaa,aaaa...` example: please give one, in Java syntax, for 4^3. Possible solutions depend on circumstances (see [Ealon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34665258/3789665) depending on guesswork) - please provide upfront as much as you deem likely to be relevant.

Comment: Example of 2^2 -  aa,ab,ba,bb.                                                           Example 2^3 - aaa, aab,aba , abb, baa, bab, bab, bbb

Comment: If there is information that would make the question a better question, edit the question. _If_ you "reply" on a comment instead, the author of that comment will only be notified if she is the author of the post (question or answer), _unless_ you address the comment at one user explicitly using _@Name_. So you want some information (`occurrence of min and max character` - that needs clarification, too) about _all_ strings of a given length (up to 90) over an alphabet of a given size (<=90, too). There isn't enough time left to iterate them before our sun dies - you need a better _algorithm_.

Comment: If 2^2 means you want all of the combinations of 2 characters taken 2 at a time (i.e. aa, ab, ba, bb), and 2^3 means all the combinations of 2 characters taken 3 at a time (there are 8 of them), then 90^90 means all combinations of 90 characters taken 90 at a time. Right? If so, that's 7.61 e175 combinations. If you could do a billion per second, it'd take you on the order of 2.4 e159 *years* to do it. So either I'm misunderstanding your question and your comments, or you misunderstand the problem. Unless you have access to one heck of a super computer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a HashMap. As there are 26 letters, you can just use `int[] count = new int[26];` to count each letter. So when you have 10 `a`s, you just set `count['a' - 97] = 10` which is `count[0] = 10`. And at the same time, use `int min = 0, max = 0;`to keep track of the min and max when you iterate the String and write into `count` array. This is `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there are only 26 possible characters? I didn't see that in his problem description.

Comment: @JimMischel That is just my guess. He can change the length of the array if he knows how many different characters there are.